# Freezes on boot but works after hard reboot

Tags: windows-10, boot, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Y501P laptop with a strange issue. When I boot it up, it will freeze, either at the Lenovo logo or once it hits the desktop (auto login) or a few seconds afterward. I’ll hold down the power button to turn it off and then try again. It will freeze a second time. I’ll hard reboot it again and Windows will offer some recovery options and I’ll say no just reboot. Then it boots just fine. And it will continue to boot just fine for some time afterward. But then next day it starts all over again. I’ve replaced the hard drive with an SSD and installed Windows 10 from scratch and the issue still persisted. I tried doing driver updates and still didn’t fix it. How can I get this laptop to boot reliably? Thanks.

Comment: First thing to do is update UEFI. And make sure Windows 10 is actually installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: Ok how do I do that?

Comment: Go to the manufacturer's website and find it at in the drivers' section. Obs.: Lenovo does NOT officially support Windows 10 for Y501P.

Comment: When you say "When I boot it up", what do you mean? Are you booting from a normal shut-down (ie hibernation, by default)? If so, you may have to change the advanced power settings to do a hard shut-down.

Comment: @AFH It’s from a complete shutdown. That’s the strange thing that it would give two different results both from a complete shutdown.

Comment: That's why I asked the question: one could have been return from hibernation and the other a cold start. As you say, it's very strange: the symptoms suggest a hardware problem. Is the battery easily removable? I ask, because a few years ago I occasionally had to do this on a dual-boot system when switching between Linux and Windows - it seemed that one OS left something in a state that the other couldn't initialise: removing the battery made sure that all the hardware had a complete power-off, while the battery apparently kept some power on somewhere. It's a long shot, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: By the way, My laptop was also a Lenovo - a G580. Recent OS releases have removed the problem, but @MichaelBay's comment about Win10 support suggests a possibly related problem with some of the hardware.